# Upload Azure blob file to nested folders in storage account container

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload azure blob file to a nested folder structure as:

[Blob Storage snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oaI2.png)

I was **able to successfully upload** the file to the parent container which is "testblobupload".

Following is my code which might look huge block, really sorry:

```
                var containerNameToUploadTheFile = applyConfirmPriceConfig.AzureBlobStorageContainerNameConfig; // Default container name where file will be saved.

                //Azure Blob Storage Temp Storage Container
                var connectionString = applyConfirmPriceConfig.AzureBlobStorageContainerConnectionString;

                var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerNameToUploadTheFile);

                var id = eventObject.Id;

                var sbmessage = new ServiceBusMessage();
                sbmessage.MessageId = eventObject.Id.ToString();

                sbmessage.Subject = eventObject.GetType().Name.Replace(ServiceBusConstants.IntegrationEventSuffix, string.Empty).Trim();

                BlobUploadOptions options = new BlobUploadOptions
                {
                    TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
                    {
                        // Set the maximum number of workers that 
                        // may be used in a parallel transfer.
                        MaximumConcurrency = 20,

                        // Set the maximum length of a transfer to 5MB.
                        // Set the maximum length of a transfer to 262144 = 256KB. This is service bus message size in standard
                        MaximumTransferSize = 0x40000, //50 * 1024,// * 1024,
                        InitialTransferLength = 0x40000,
                    },
                    HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "application/json" }
                };

                fileName = $"{$"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHMM}"}_{sbmessage.Subject}_{sbmessage.MessageId}";
                var memorystream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventObject)));
                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{$"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd}"}/{fileName}");
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(memorystream, options);
        }
```

I tried changing the container name to "testblobupload/TransactionalData/BACKTRACK" but that doesn't work.

Please suggest and guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the following line of code:

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{$"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd}"}/{fileName}");
```

to

```
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"TransactionalData/BACKTRACK/{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMdd}/{fileName}");
```